# Buttons shifting locations after disabling status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, statusbar

I built my app, it looked fine in the interface builder, it looked fine on my iPhone. The status bar was showing, so I went into "info.plist" and changed "status bar is initially hidden" to YES. Now when I run the app on my iPhone, buttons near the bottom of the screen have shifted up to what looks like the exact width of a status bar. Although in the storyboard, the buttons appear in the correct position.

If anyone has any input, it will be greatly appreciated. I was just about finished with the app, now I am running in circles trying to straighten this out... I hope someone can make some sense out of all this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status bar is a pain in the butt.  When you set it initially hidden; it shifts your entire view up 20 px to compensate, which makes a navigationController draw itself up inside the status bar, so you spend your time adding a 20 px y offset to everything.

Yet, when it is turned off, your get a 20 px black space when you decide to hide the navigationBar in the future.  It does, however, draw everything correctly.

My advice: Unless your splash screen absolutely must have that extra 20 px, or you are opening with a movie, don't hide the status bar.

Comment: Thanks, I am now displaying the status bar again and everything is fine. I guess on my next project I'll hide status bar before I do anything else.

Comment: As long as it stays hidden throughout the run-time of the application you should be good.